# Optimize double loop//make selection in python or mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a structure

```
locations : { //info,
             "events" :[ { //data
                          "displayed" : True},
                          { //data
                          "displayed" : False}
                       ]
             }
```

Each location has many events where we define if the event will be displayed or not.

My python code:

```
#load the data
locations = db.col.find({'events.displayed': True})
#remove manually
for l in locations:
    for e in l['events']:
        if e['displayed'] == False:
            #this item should be deleted
            print e
```

I know that `{'events.displayed': True}` can be satisfied if only a `events.displayed` is true and it will return the whole item.

I want to ask if I can ignore in my `find()` call those items with `"displayed" : False`. If that cannot happen with pymongo, I want to remove manually with python the item with the `"displayed" : False` in an optimized (because of the double loop) way (maybe something with itertools library?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can fetch only those items with `"displayed": True` using the MongoDB's [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/). Here's a sample code.

```
db.locations.aggregate([{'$unwind': '$events'}, {'$match': {'events.displayed': True}}])
```

With `db.locations.find` you'll have to filter those elements on Python code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a "[projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)" to tell the server to send only the matching portions of the array:

```
for doc in locations.find(
        {'events.displayed': True},
        {'events': {'$elemMatch': {'displayed': True}}}):
    print doc
```

Note that this only returns the **first** matching array element. If you need all matching elements, your Python loop is the best way to go.